# How to send JSON to server with jqGrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, post, jqgrid

[EDIT] (I couldn't wait 3 hours to answer my question):
Well, it appears it is not the jqGrid component which is in fault, thanks to TheCodeDestroyer for figured it out.

I tested this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<title>My First Grid</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="./css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="./css/ui.jqgrid.css" />

<style>
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
}
</style>

<script src="./js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="./js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="./js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">


$(function () {
    $("#list").jqGrid({        
        url:'datas.php',
        datatype: "json",
        mtype: "GET",
        colNames: ["ID","Client", "Projet", "Tache", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31"],
            colModel: [
                { name: "id_record", width: 55, hidden:false},
                { name: "client", width: 55, sortable:true},
                { name: "projet", width: 150, align: "right", sortable:true},
                { name: "tache", width: 150, align: "right", sortable:true},
                { name: "un", width: 20, align: "right", sortable:false, editable: true,  edittype: "select",editoptions: { value: "1:1; 0.5:0.5; 0.25:0.25" } },
                { name: "deux", width: 20, align: "right", sortable:false, editable: true,  edittype: "select",editoptions: { value: "1:1; 0.5:0.5; 0.25:0.25" }  },
                { name: "trois", width: 20, align: "right", sortable:false, editable: true,  edittype: "select",editoptions: { value: "1:1; 0.5:0.5; 0.25:0.25" }  },
                { name: "quatre", width: 20, align: "right", sortable:false, editable: true,  edittype: "select",editoptions: { value: "1:1; 0.5:0.5; 0.25:0.25" }  },
                { name: "cinq", width: 20, align: "right", sortable:false, editable: true,  edittype: "select",editoptions: { value: "1:1; 0.5:0.5; 0.25:0.25" }  },
                { name: "six", width: 20, align: "right", sortable:false, editable: true,  edittype: "select",editoptions: { value: "1:1; 0.5:0.5; 0.25:0.25" }  },
                { name: "sept", width: 20, align: "right", sortable:false, editable: true,  edittype: "select",editoptions: { value: "1:1; 0.5:0.5; 0.25:0.25" }  },
                { name: "huit", width: 20, align: "right", sortable:false, editable: true,  edittype: "select",editoptions: { value: "1:1; 0.5:0.5; 0.25:0.25" }  },
                { name: "neuf", width: 20, align: "right", sortable:false, editable: true,  edittype: "select",editoptions: { value: "1:1; 0.5:0.5; 0.25:0.25" }  },
                { name: "dix", width: 20, align: "right", sortable:false, editable: true,  edittype: "select",editoptions: { value: "1:1; 0.5:0.5; 0.25:0.25" }  },
                { name: "onze", width: 20, align: "right", sortable:false, editable: true,  edittype: "select",editoptions: { value: "1:1; 0.5:0.5; 0.25:0.25" }  },
                { name: "douze", width: 20, align: "right", sortable:false, editable: true,  edittype: "select",editoptions: { value: "1:1; 0.5:0.5; 0.25:0.25" }  },
                { name: "treize", width: 20, align: "right", sortable:false, editable: true,  edittype: "select",editoptions: { value: "1:1; 0.5:0.5; 0.25:0.25" }  },
                { name: "quatorze", width: 20, align: "right", sortable:false, editable: true,  edittype: "select",editoptions: { value: "1:1; 0.5:0.5; 0.25:0.25" }  },
                { name: "quinze", width: 20, align: "right", sortable:false, editable: true,  edittype: "select",editoptions: { value: "1:1; 0.5:0.5; 0.25:0.25" }  },
                { name: "seize", width: 20, align: "right", sortable:false, editable: true,  edittype: "select",editoptions: { value: "1:1; 0.5:0.5; 0.25:0.25" }  },
                { name: "dix-sept", width: 20, align: "right", sortable:false, editable: true,  edittype: "select",editoptions: { value: "1:1; 0.5:0.5; 0.25:0.25" }  },
                { name: "dix-huit", width: 20, align: "right", sortable:false, editable: true,  edittype: "select",editoptions: { value: "1:1; 0.5:0.5; 0.25:0.25" }  },
                { name: "dix-neuf", width: 20, align: "right", sortable:false, editable: true,  edittype: "select",editoptions: { value: "1:1; 0.5:0.5; 0.25:0.25" }  },
                { name: "vingt", width: 20, align: "right", sortable:false, editable: true,  edittype: "select",editoptions: { value: "1:1; 0.5:0.5; 0.25:0.25" }  },
                { name: "vingt-et-un", width: 20, align: "right", sortable:false, editable: true,  edittype: "select",editoptions: { value: "1:1; 0.5:0.5; 0.25:0.25" }  },
                { name: "vingt-deux", width: 20, align: "right", sortable:false, editable: true,  edittype: "select",editoptions: { value: "1:1; 0.5:0.5; 0.25:0.25" }  },
                { name: "vingt-trois", width: 20, align: "right", sortable:false, editable: true,  edittype: "select",editoptions: { value: "1:1; 0.5:0.5; 0.25:0.25" }  },
                { name: "vingt-quatre", width: 20, align: "right", sortable:false, editable: true,  edittype: "select",editoptions: { value: "1:1; 0.5:0.5; 0.25:0.25" }  },
                { name: "vingt-cinq", width: 20, align: "right", sortable:false, editable: true,  edittype: "select",editoptions: { value: "1:1; 0.5:0.5; 0.25:0.25" }  },
                { name: "vingt-six", width: 20, align: "right", sortable:false, editable: true,  edittype: "select",editoptions: { value: "1:1; 0.5:0.5; 0.25:0.25" }  },
                { name: "vingt-sept", width: 20, align: "right", sortable:false, editable: true,  edittype: "select",editoptions: { value: "1:1; 0.5:0.5; 0.25:0.25" }  },
                { name: "vingt-huit", width: 20, align: "right", sortable:false, editable: true,  edittype: "select",editoptions: { value: "1:1; 0.5:0.5; 0.25:0.25" }  },
                { name: "vingt-neuf", width: 20, align: "right", sortable:false, editable: true,  edittype: "select",editoptions: { value: "1:1; 0.5:0.5; 0.25:0.25" }  },
                { name: "trente", width: 20, align: "right", sortable:false, editable: true,  edittype: "select",editoptions: { value: "1:1; 0.5:0.5; 0.25:0.25" }  },
                { name: "trente-et-un", width: 20, align: "right", sortable:false, editable: true,  edittype: "select",editoptions: { value: "1:1; 0.5:0.5; 0.25:0.25" } },


            ],
        height: '100%',
        cellEdit: true,
        cellsubmit: 'remote',
        cellurl: "https://ort8m12c8ckf.runscope.net",
        pager: "#pager",
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30],
        sortname: "id_record",
        sortorder: "asc",
        viewrecords: true,
        gridview: true,
        autoencode: true,
        caption: "My first grid",
        ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json"},
        ajaxCellOptions: { contentType: "application/json"},
        ajaxRowOptions: { contentType: "application/json"},
        beforeSubmitCell : function(rowid,celname,value,iRow,iCol) {

                selectedRowId = $('#list').jqGrid ('getGridParam', 'selrow');
                cellValue = $('#list').jqGrid('getCell', selectedRowId, 'id_record');   
                v = JSON.stringify({valeur: value,nom_cellule: celname,id_record: cellValue});
                send(v);
                return v; 
        },


       // serializeRowData: function (data) { alert("ok"); return JSON.stringify(data); },


    })
function send(datas){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            url: 'https://ort8m12c8ckf.runscope.net',
            data: datas,
            dataType: "json"
        });
}
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <table id="list"><tr><td></td></tr></table> 
    <div id="pager"></div> 
    <input type="button" value="send"></input>

</body>
</html>
```

So TheCodeDestroyer gave all the answers possible, and if you are in the same situation, it is probably due to your server or something like that. I posted a new topic concerning this new question [just there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18465767/i-cannot-send-json).

[HERE IS THE FIRST QUESTION]

I am looking for a way to send JSON to server with jqGrid since yesterday. And I have still no answer.

So here is my grid:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<title>My First Grid</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="./css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="./css/ui.jqgrid.css" />

<style>
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
}
</style>

<script src="./js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="./js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="./js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">


$(function () {
    $("#list").jqGrid({        
        url:'datas.php',
        datatype: "json",
        mtype: "GET",
        colNames: ["ID","Client", "Projet", "Tache", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31"],
            colModel: [
                { name: "id_record", width: 55, hidden:false},
                { name: "client", width: 55, sortable:true},
                { name: "projet", width: 150, align: "right", sortable:true},
                { name: "tache", width: 150, align: "right", sortable:true},
                { name: "un", width: 20, align: "right", sortable:false, editable: true, key: false },
                { name: "deux", width: 20, align: "right", sortable:false, editable: true, key: false },
                { name: "trois", width: 20, align: "right", sortable:false, editable: true, key: false },
                { name: "quatre", width: 20, align: "right", sortable:false, editable: true, key: false },
                { name: "cinq", width: 20, align: "right", sortable:false, editable: true, key: false },
                { name: "six", width: 20, align: "right", sortable:false, editable: true, key: false },
                { name: "sept", width: 20, align: "right", sortable:false, editable: true, key: false },
                { name: "huit", width: 20, align: "right", sortable:false, editable: true, key: false },
                { name: "neuf", width: 20, align: "right", sortable:false, editable: true, key: false },
                { name: "dix", width: 20, align: "right", sortable:false, editable: true, key: false },
                { name: "onze", width: 20, align: "right", sortable:false, editable: true, key: false },
                { name: "douze", width: 20, align: "right", sortable:false, editable: true, key: false },
                { name: "treize", width: 20, align: "right", sortable:false, editable: true, key: false },
                { name: "quatorze", width: 20, align: "right", sortable:false, editable: true, key: false },
                { name: "quinze", width: 20, align: "right", sortable:false, editable: true, key: false },
                { name: "seize", width: 20, align: "right", sortable:false, editable: true, key: false },
                { name: "dix-sept", width: 20, align: "right", sortable:false, editable: true, key: false },
                { name: "dix-huit", width: 20, align: "right", sortable:false, editable: true, key: false },
                { name: "dix-neuf", width: 20, align: "right", sortable:false, editable: true, key: false },
                { name: "vingt", width: 20, align: "right", sortable:false, editable: true, key: false },
                { name: "vingt-et-un", width: 20, align: "right", sortable:false, editable: true, key: false },
                { name: "vingt-deux", width: 20, align: "right", sortable:false, editable: true, key: false },
                { name: "vingt-trois", width: 20, align: "right", sortable:false, editable: true, key: false },
                { name: "vingt-quatre", width: 20, align: "right", sortable:false, editable: true, key: false },
                { name: "vingt-cinq", width: 20, align: "right", sortable:false, editable: true, key: false },
                { name: "vingt-six", width: 20, align: "right", sortable:false, editable: true, key: false },
                { name: "vingt-sept", width: 20, align: "right", sortable:false, editable: true, key: false },
                { name: "vingt-huit", width: 20, align: "right", sortable:false, editable: true, key: false },
                { name: "vingt-neuf", width: 20, align: "right", sortable:false, editable: true, key: false },
                { name: "trente", width: 20, align: "right", sortable:false, editable: true, key: false },
                { name: "trente-et-un", width: 20, align: "right", sortable:false, editable: true, key: false},


            ],
        height: '100%',
        cellEdit: true,
        cellsubmit: 'remote',
        cellurl: "https://ort8m12c8ckf.runscope.net",
        pager: "#pager",
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30],
        sortname: "id_record",
        sortorder: "asc",
        viewrecords: true,
        gridview: true,
        autoencode: true,
        caption: "my first grid
        gridview: true,

        beforeSubmitCell : function(rowid,celname,value,iRow,iCol) {

                selectedRowId = $('#list').jqGrid ('getGridParam', 'selrow');
                cellValue = $('#list').jqGrid('getCell', selectedRowId, 'id_record');

                return {valeur:value,nom_cellule:celname,id_record:cellValue}; 
        }

    })
});
</script>

</head>
<body>

    <table id="list"><tr><td></td></tr></table> 
    <div id="pager"></div> 
</body>
</html>
```

I am using the inline editing feature to send datas. Currently, the URL is referring a place where I can see what is posted (and it is not JSON my friends).

Your help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You actually use cell edit not inline edit... I don't get your code why do you set selectedRowId and cellValue? you should get those values through the event.

```
rowid = selectedRowId
cellValue = value
```

But to return JSON do this in beforeSubmitCell :

```
beforeSubmitCell : function(rowid,celname,value,iRow,iCol) {

            selectedRowId = $('#list').jqGrid ('getGridParam', 'selrow');
            cellValue = $('#list').jqGrid('getCell', selectedRowId, 'id_record');

            return JSON.stringify({valeur: value,nom_cellule: celname,id_record: cellValue});
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.
I pasted your code and added an alert("ok"); for the event serializeRowData, and it never appears. Is it because I use inline editing instead of form editing?

Comment: Thanks again, I thought I was using inline editing. But again, it doesn't send JSON, the content type is still "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8". I am not very familiar with JSON so maybe IT IS JSON but I really doubt about it.

Actually I use runscope.com to see the body of the request. When I opened my account, I had an example with JSON and the body was like: {"valeur":" 0.25","nom_cellule":"trois","id_record":"17"} But with my application it is more like "trois=+0.5&id=7&oper=edit"

So now the problem is: why can't I send the JSON formated datas?

Comment: Well basically you are sending JSON but your application formats it into x-www-form-urlencoded so this has more to do with you application than the jqGrid component. You can also try adding these grid options:

 {ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
 {ajaxCellOptions: { contentType: "application/json", type: "PUT" },

Comment: Still not working :/
My application is only the "index.html" file, containing the grid and datas.php, the datas provider.

Now, I the result of the request has no body, which is pretty weird.

Comment: Btw where are you checking the content in browser?

Comment: I use https://www.runscope.com/capture/ort8m12c8ckf, but if you want to check too I can use http://requestb.in/1504cq41?inspect

I am thinking that I use MAMP for my tests, could the problem be from it? I mean: is it possible that the MAMP server formats the JSON datas?

Comment: Its is possible yes. I don't think like i said that the component is the issue.